# Paging Library with database as well as Network Request

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-room, android-database

I have db with 1000's of records. I have to implement pagination so as to get 30 records at a time from db on recycler scrolling.For that I read somewhere android has an option of Paging library with ROOM. But I have to load data from Api also in my adapter. How can I use PAgedListAdapter to populate data from database as well as API.

Comment: why can't you use other adapter for data from API?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko u mean to say two Adapters to use with same recycler, one for db access and another for API response binding?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean. When you want to show DB data, you do `setAdapter(pagedListAdapter)`, and when you need from API - `setAdapter(yourAPIAdapter)`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how's this possible if I am showing 40 items, 30 might be from database and rest 10 from network, how same recyler will show data from two adapters at once?

Comment: then you should already have those items loaded, and you don't need any pagination adapters, but instead you can manually paginate your loading

Answer (score 2):

you can use [BoundryCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.BoundaryCallback) to get notified on certain points of your DB list

here is a sample from Google [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample)

here is my playground with paging [link](https://github.com/worldsnas/PagingLibraryTest)

Comment: thanks for ur help, but how can I get same code in Java?

Comment: Kotlin is very easy to read but if you reply me with the specific class you need in java I can convert and update my answer